# Different periodical lag in two time series and different periodical correlation interpretation

Tags: correlation, cross-correlation, lags

I am working on two stock price movements over 2 years, a minute by minute change (over 1m rows). I ran cross correlation after making them stationary. There is a result that I am kind of confused with.

1. r shows two stocks are moderately correlated without any change in the interval. But, when I change the time interval of price change from 'minute by minute' to 10 minute, r gets much higher, showing almost a perfect linear relationship.
2. When I apply lag on one of the two stock price movements in either minute by minute or 10 minute basis, r shows no correlation.

What I am stuck in is, the two stock price movements are identical when looked into in a 10 minute interval while quite different in a minute interval. I am guessing that one of stocks moves differently from the other, and then eventually follows and gets identical with the other every 10  minute.

If it's true, there must be lag in its movement. It can be inconsistent (inconstant) one because I saw no lagged correlation from lagging one of the two movements as a whole.

**I would like to know what method I can use to find out whether there is an inconstant or inconsistent lag in one of the movements. Also, I would like to know if there's a way to identify every period where lag exists and how long it is in each lagged period.**

I first thought of DTW matrix, but it doesn't seem to be a proper one in my case.

Simple search terms would help a lot too.

Comment: It sounds to me like the stocks may move together, but their minute-by-minute price movements are possibly quite noisy. But after ten minutes that noise is less meaningful, so the signal is more apparent. You might try looking at hourly and daily prices, too. I suspect that you'll see a continuing trend of greater correlation because the short-term noise gets less important. Under this theory there is no lag that would align the prices, because there is no lag in the signal, and the noise is random.

Comment: @Wesley Thank you so much. Exactly as you said, there's a trend of greater correlation when I look at hourly and daily prices. Could you tell me more about the short-term noise, please? Should I do something about it, and if so, is there a way to handle the noise? Frankly speaking I always get confused with the concept of noise...

Comment: Well, I can only guess. But I suspect that the minute-by-minute price fluctuations would be from random variation - buyers and sellers in a tug-of-war that goes back and forth in the short term, even if they are overall moving in a consistent long-term direction. I'm not an expert in stock analysis so I can't really say how to "handle" the noise. You can drive yourself crazy trying to find an explanation for every little difference.

Comment: @Wesley Thank you again. I just want to know what to do with noise when analyzing correlation between two time series in general, not particularly stocks. When I am not interested in knowing an explanation for every little difference, I can leave it as it is? Or, should I minimize the noise? What method do I use when minimizing the noise?